# Magento 2 - How to customize packing slip pdf print-out

Tags: magento2, pdf, print, packing-slip

I want to change the design and layout of my `packing-slip` `pdf print-outs` to make a simple and clean print for the employes to work through.

Is there any extension / tutorial / anything else which shows how to make this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit the packing list, or any other PDF docs such as invoice you need to override the files contained within

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf
```

For example if wanted to add the price to the packing list

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment"
                type="Example\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment"/>

</config>
```

Then copy the file "Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment" to your app/code file, change the name spacing to match the XML above and add the following on around line number 81

```
 // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 395;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 70;
        $feedTax = $feedSubtotal + 70;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['price'],
                'feed' => $feedPrice,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => $feedTax,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks its works but in $item = $this->getItem(); some data are missing like subtotal, tax etc. can you tell me how can I fetch all the data in $item ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this module
https://www.vnecoms.com/magento2-pdf-invoice-pro.html. This module allow you customize your template directly inside backend. Use editor allow you can create template in a few clicks. Support magento 2.2.x

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you already did this, but for future people that come across this, here is a video that somehow explains it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_baegIF0v48&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This is a very bad procedure as the files will be overwritten with future Magento updates.