# How to create custom order PDF in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, invoice, pdf

Can anyone help to create custom order PDF template for our drop shipper?

Answer (score 3):

There are several extensions to do this, some of them for free

https://marketplace.magento.com/eadesignro-module-pdfgenerator.html

If you want a code approach, take a look here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198001/3566

Comment: Explain downvote reason, please

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't give you downvote. It's given by someone else.